# Vim Iterm extremely slow and laggy compared to Linux machine with same setup

Tags: terminal, performance, vim, iterm

Vim and iterm is very slow on macos. There is noticeable lag when scrolling down the page when holding down jk. Many plugins also slow down vm dramatically such as `syntastic`. For example, with `syntastic` enabled, there is a noticeable delay between when i press `:w` and when the cursor goes back to the line that I was previously on. When I use vim with the same exact `.vimrc` configuration on a Linux machine, everything seems buttery smooth. I have seen posts that suggest using `Alacritty` but there is a lot of functionality that is lacking on it.

Does anyone have any tips to speed up iterm and vim?

Comment: It's not an answer, but I found the same. I tried removing the vim config thinking it was something there. I tried different fonts, turning off cursor guides, enabling acceleration. Finally I just gave up and moved back to Terminal.app. Yeah, it's sucky, but faster 8(